# Why am I getting a java.lang.Charsequence cannot be applied to a char error?

Tags: string, char, charsequence

```
 }else if(readUserEmail.contains('a')){
        System.out.print("true");
```

Why am I getting a `java.lang.Charsequence` cannot be applied to a char error? In this case `readUserEmail` is a string of an email.

Answer (score 1):

The `contains` method of the `String` class takes a `CharSequence` as an argument, but you are providing a character literal as indicated by using single quotes.

Change your `'a'` to `"a"`. Double quotes are for `String` (which implements the `CharSequence` interface) and single quotes are for characters.